# Nanoseconds exhibit strange behaviour

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have the following goal: convert a date-time string to a nanoseconds integer in python.

Here is what I find strange in the process:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_str = '2015-01-08T08:23:21.301812Z'

nanoseconds = 1000000000
datetime_nanoseconds = int(datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ').timestamp() * nanoseconds)
```

When I print `datetime_nanoseconds` I get the following number `1420701801301811968`.

**First question**: Where did the last three number `968` come from? I was expecting `1420701801301812000`

Surprisingly if I divide `1420701801301811968 / nanoseconds` I get the value I expect `1420701801.30181`2 in seconds and these last three digits disappeared now.

**Second question**: Why did the last three digits disappear now?

I get the feeling that python is not great for working with sub microsecond time...

Any help on the subject would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`datetime.timestamp()` returns a floating point value.  Unlike Python's integers, floating point values do not have infinite precision.  A double-precision float has about 17 digits of precision, and you're exceeding that.  So, don't use `timestamp()`.  Fetch the integer value of `timestamp()`, multiply by 1000000, add the `microsecond` value, and multiply by 1000.

Comment: Sounds legit. .